# Escape <a href> tags while using simple_format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where I would like to display the line breaks in the content of a text_area.

I know I can accomplish this using simple_format, but for SEO reasons I would also like to disallow them from inserting links into the content.

How do I go about displaying the line breaks, and not render the `<a>` tags ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `simple_format` with `sanitize`:

```
# prints <p>foo\n<br />barbaz</p>
simple_format sanitize("foo\nbar<a href='foo'>baz</a>", :tags => [])
```

Pass allowable tags as the `:tags` option (e.g. `:tags => ["p", "em"]`).